# Changing the opacity of stroke

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to adjust opacity of stroke without interfering with the fill of the shape because every time i try to adjust both changes.

Comment: Can you please include a picture of what you are getting, and what is your desired result?

Comment: @Juancho I think it's pretty clear. Just the stroke of a shape to be transparent, and the fill to stay opaque. (If you adjust the stroke of a shape: It applies to both the fill and stroke)

Answer (score 7):

Stoke and fill opacity *are* independent.

There are three opacity settings shown on the **Fill and Stroke** pane; one each on the **Fill** and **Stroke** tabs and those only affect those. Below everything else is *Blur(%)* and *Opacity (%)*. Those settings apply to the whole object.

Opacity for the stroke or fill is actually part of its color. It is the color channel labeled *A* (for alpha). Opacity 255 is solid; 0 is fully transparent.

It sounds like you are changing the slider labeled opacity below the Fill and Stroke tabs. Again, that opacity is for the entire object. Change the alpha channel in the stroke color instead.